# Need help in proving a small part of a theorem-

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If $2^p(\vert f_n \vert^p+\vert f \vert^p)-\vert f_n-f \vert^p \geq 0$ then how would I show $$2^{p+1} \int \vert f \vert^p=\int \lim_{n\to \infty}[2^p(\vert f_n \vert^p+\vert f \vert^p)-\vert f_n \vert^p].$$

This I found while proving:

> Let {$f_n$ } be a sequence in $L^p,1\leq p <\infty,$ such that $f_n
>  \rightarrow f  $ a.e and $f \in L^p$.If $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_p =
>  ||f||_{p}$,then $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n-f||_{p}=0$

I wanted to know how it happened?
Need help!!!

Comment: Statement of theorem:Let {$f_n$ } be a sequence in $L^p,1\leq p <\infty,$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f  $ a.e and $f \in L^p$.If $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_p = ||f||_{p}$,then $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n-f||_{p}=0$

Comment: Thanks for your responsiveness, Urysohn!  My comments seem no longer to apply, so I will delete them.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the dominated convergence theorem? See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Dominated_convergence_in_Lp-spaces_.28corollary.29).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri:I got how it followed from Dominated convergence theorem,but how to show  the original clain of O.P?

Comment: I don't think the claim is actually true. Let $f_n=f$ for all $n$. The equality would imply

$$\int 2^{p+1}{|f|}^p = \int \left(2^{p+1}-1\right){|f|}^p$$

Comment: @Fimpellizieri:You're right actually that there is misprinting in the book that's why the clain is not holding.